# what parameters affect the smallest eigenvalue of an asymmetrix matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a problem which produces matrix $A$ as a result. The smallest eigenvalue of it's inverse ($A^{-1}$) and $trace(A^{-1})$ is important for me. In my problem these have almost the same value. The way which the matrix $A$ is produced is complex and consist integral and products. Now my question is that, what parameters in the original matrix $A$ is important which affect the smallest eigenvalue of the it's inverse $A^{-1}$ or $trace(A^{-1})$? is it possible to estimate that the smallest eigenvalue of the inverse $A$ or its trace is small or high before calculating?

Comment: If you know a is invertible, is there any reason you are looking for the smallest eigenvalue of the inverse rather than the largest eigenvalue of A?

Comment: A first thing : do you mean the smallest eigenvalue in absolute value -= module) ? Or the smallest = $\lambda_{min} $ where $\lambda_{min} =\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 \cdots$ (but this would mean that these eigenvalues are all real... which is not in general the case).

Comment: In addition to Stens commment: every eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is also an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $\frac 1{\lambda}$.

Comment: @Sten yes your are correct. actually I'm using both smallest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ and $trace(A^{-1})$. So I said the invers of $A$. let me to correct my question

Comment: @Keinstein yes, as I am using also $trace(A{-1})$, I said smallest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. I have corrected my question